# XSLT: Copy an element with all attributes where an attribute matches a value

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given an XML structure like follows:

```
<Resources PossibleAttribute="SomethingHere">
  <Book ID="1" OtherAttribute="abc" />
  <Book ID="2" DifferentAttribute="def" />
</Resources>
```

I need to copy the structure and element where `ID='1'`. So I'm looking to end up with:

```
<Resources PossibleAttribute="SomethingHere">
  <Book ID="1" OtherAttribute="abc" />
</Resources>
```

What I've come up with thus far is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Resources">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Book[@ID='1']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, however, is not producing the intended end result, giving me this instead:

```
<Resources>
  <Book>1</Book>
</Resources>
```

A key item here is that any of these elements may contain additional attributes that are not specified here or currently known. Hence, if additional attributes are present, they too should be copied.

Any tips you can offer would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Resources">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Book[@ID=1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why not? Because I am not smart enough to understand XSL, that's why not :)
Thank you!